# Class loading issue

Tags: java, classloader

I successfully loaded a class at runtime, and called newInstance() on that class, and created an object from it.

But, later on in the program, I am trying to find that class again by name. And for some reason, the program can't find it.

Here's the code:

```
MyClassLoader mcl = new MyClassLoader();
Class<?> c = mcl.loadClass("models." + getModelClassName(), getByteCode());
```

here is the loadClass method in MyClassLoader:

```
   public Class<?> loadClass(String className, byte[] classData){
           return this.defineClass(className,classData,0,classData.length);
        }
```

Anyway, it appears I have successfully loaded the class, because I can call newInstance on the newly loaded class "c":

```
     Object o = c.newInstance();
```

(So, no problems, yet).

However, later on in the program, I make the following call:

```
Class<? extends DB4oModel> dbClass = null;

try{

   dbClass = (Class<? extends DB4oModel>) Class.forName("models."+className);

} catch(ClassNotFoundException e1){

      // this exception is thrown by my program !!

}
```

My only guess as to what the problem could be is that the class has been successfully loaded for one classloader but the other classloader doesn't know about the class?
I really have no idea. Please help, thanks.

Comment: Will you please share the Exception that you are getting??

Comment: I think your thoughts are true. Why dont you get the instance using your class loader, rather that using class.forname

Comment: Exception is:  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: models.MyModelClass  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source). etc...

Comment: @Subin, ok I could try that, but how do I do that (get instance via class loader?) I actually need the Class object itself, not an instance of the Class.

Comment: @AlexMills As you said : `MyClassLoader mcl = new MyClassLoader();
Class<?> c = mcl.loadClass("models." + getModelClassName(), getByteCode());` `Object o = c.newInstance();`

Comment: As the answer says class.forname can accept classloader used to load the the class. ` public static Class<?> forName(String name, boolean initialize, ClassLoader loader) throws ClassNotFoundException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the classloader (which has loaded your model class) as a parameter in Class.forName();

See [this!](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29)